# Is it safe to load a partial view which gets its name from route parameter in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering if it is safe to load Partial View that takes the name from route parameter?

For example with the following URL

mydomain.com/home/services/selling

I want the view to load partial view named `selling`

This is the code in the view:

```
string SubPage = ViewBag.SubPage;
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Pages/Services/"+SubPage)
```

Is this safe or should I add some sort of sanitization?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

I am not worried if the user accesses views under Services as all of those views are already accessible through site navigation.

I am more interested if the subpage can be set so it loads a view from outside the `~/Views/Pages/Services/` folder,like a view in Account folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The harm would be if the act of someone can modifying `SubPage` such that it displays a page under `~/Views/Pages/Services/` causes them to gain access to a route they should not be allowed.

This could happen if you are using common access control models that verify that the user is allowed to perform the given controller action, without doing an extra check that the `SubPage` is allowed to them.